# How to use php variable (array, returned from sq1) in another query sq2 in one php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.location,
        site.slc_info.sitename,
        SUM(IF(hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.model_name like '%3%', hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.installed_qty, 0)) AS p2,
        SUM(IF(hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.model_name like '%5%', hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.installed_qty, 0)) AS p3
        FROM hwewo.sams_inventory_detail
            INNER JOIN site.slc_info ON hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.location = site.slc_info.site_loc_code          
            INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT hwewo.ewox_radio_design.site_loc_code
                    FROM hwewo.ewox_radio_design) as dt1 ON hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.location = dt1.site_loc_code            
        WHERE 
        hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.model_name like '%pR%'
        GROUP BY
                hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.location
        ";

        if ($case == '2x'){ 
            $sql .= "
                HAVING
                p2 <> 0
            ";
        }   

        else ($case == '3x'){   
            $sql .= "
                HAVING
                p3 <> 0
                ";
        }   
        
    //Build up Array
    $location = array();
    $sitename = array();
    $p2 = array();
    $p3 = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($ewocon, $sql);  
    
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {       
        array_push($location, $row['location']);
        array_push($sitename, $row['sitename']);
        array_push($p2, $row['p2']);
        array_push($p3, $row['p3']);


    }   
    
        $sq2 = "
        SELECT 
        hwewo.ewox_radio_design.site_loc_code
        FROM 
        hwewo.ewox_radio_design     
        WHERE
        hwewo.ewox_radio_design.site_loc_code = '.$location[i].'";
    
    $site_loc_code = array();
    $result1 = mysqli_query($ewocon, $sq2);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {       
        array_push($site_loc_code, $row['site_loc_code']);
    }   
    
       echo "<table id = myTable>";
    
    if($excelView == "1"){                      //excel view title bar
    
        
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Site Loc Code</th>";
        echo "<th>Site Name</th>";
        echo "<th>2.0</th>";
        echo "<th>3.0</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    
        printf($location[0]);
        printf($site_loc_code[0]);

    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($location); $i++)
    {
        
        if ($excelView == "1"){         //echo database data to excel view
            

            echo "<tr>";    
            echo "<td><input type='button' class='collapsible' value='$location[$i]'>   
            <div class='content'>
            <p>$site_loc_code[$i]  $location[$i]</p>
            </div></td> ";
            echo "<td>".$sitename[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$p2[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$p3[$i]."</td>";
```

Here are part of my code, got trouble in creating a new query (sq2) and want to use the result ($location) as a condition to figure out the desired information from db into sq2 which is array.

For example:

```
$location[0] = AAA
$location[1] = BBB
$location[2] = CCC
```

I am trying to use the as a condtion
`hwewo.ewox_radio_design.site_loc_code = '.$location[i].'`

so that the result of $site_loc_code[0] is AAA
Do I need to figure out how to use variable in sq2 or other thing else?

---

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.location,
        site.slc_info.sitename,
        SUM(IF(hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.model_name like '%3%', hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.installed_qty, 0)) AS p2,
        SUM(IF(hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.model_name like '%5%', hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.installed_qty, 0)) AS p3
        FROM hwewo.sams_inventory_detail
            INNER JOIN site.slc_info ON hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.location = site.slc_info.site_loc_code          
            INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT hwewo.ewox_radio_design.site_loc_code
                    FROM hwewo.ewox_radio_design) as dt1 ON hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.location = dt1.site_loc_code            
        WHERE 
        hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.model_name like '%pR%'
        GROUP BY
                hwewo.sams_inventory_detail.location
        ";

        if ($case == '2x'){ 
            $sql .= "
                HAVING
                p2 <> 0
            ";
        }   

        else ($case == '3x'){   
            $sql .= "
                HAVING
                p3 <> 0
                ";
        }   

    //Build up Array
    $location = array();
    $sitename = array();
    $p2 = array();
    $p3 = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($ewocon, $sql);  


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {       
        array_push($location, $row['location']);
        array_push($sitename, $row['sitename']);
        array_push($p2, $row['p2']);
        array_push($p3, $row['p3']);


    }   
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($location); $i++)
    {
        $sq2 = "
        SELECT 
        hwewo.ewox_radio_design.site_loc_code
        FROM 
        hwewo.ewox_radio_design     
        WHERE
        hwewo.ewox_radio_design.site_loc_code = '"$location[i]"'
        ";
    
        $site_loc_code = array();
        
        $result1 = mysqli_query($ewocon, $sq2);
    
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
        {       
            array_push($site_loc_code, $row['site_loc_code']);
        }   
    
        if ($excelView == "1"){         //echo database data to excel view
            
            echo "<tr>";    

            //echo "<td>".$location[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='button' class='collapsible' value='$location[$i]'>   
            <div class='content'>
            <p>$site_loc_code[$i]$location[$i]</p>
            </div></td> ";
            echo "<td>".$sitename[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$p2[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$p3[$i]."</td>";
```

Comment: 1) it would need to be `$location[$i]` (so `$i` would be a proper PHP variable) and 2) then you'd need to put `$sq2` inside a loop where you're looping through the $location array and incrementing `$i` (e.g. later on you've got `for($i = 0 ; $i < count($location); $i++)`, so you'd either need to move the code into that loop, or make another one just like it)

Comment: those `sq2........to........arraypush` are in the for loop now, but seems still cant perform `site_loc_code[i]`, only got `location[i]` at the present. Am I got wrong concept on using a array as a condtion in sq2? Or this is work for me?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Please 1) add your updated version of the code to the question, and 2) explain exactly what goes wrong when you try to access the site_loc_code data - do you get an error? Or unexpected result?

Comment: I'd recommend you to combine your 2 queries into one.

Comment: @ADyson updated latest code at the bottom, which inserted all code related to sq2 into the for loop. I don't sure this condition `hwewo.ewox_radio_design.site_loc_code = '"$location[i]"'` work or not. No any result for `$site_loc_code[i]` at the present. Since I use printf to check result, `$location[i]` are showed normally. It should be alias with `$site_loc_code[i]`, but location[i] only content single row, site_loc_code[i] content at least 5 rows.

Comment: @Akina Do you mean I can use UNION in sq1 to add sq2?

Comment: `'"$location[i]"'` looks like a syntax error, if you want to concatenate the strings I'd expect `'".$location[i]."'` . Is PHP not complaining about a syntax error there??

Comment: Yes, here are a syntax error. I tried to created a variable `$test = 'AAA'` and proved it, either use `'$test'` or `'".$test."'` is fine. On the other hand, seems it still cant show the proper result. suppose `$site_loc_code` got more than 1 row, even though the while loop is added

Comment: UNION is not applicable. You must JOIN this two queries into one (as CTEs, if server version allows, or as subqueries). And avoid direct code building, use parameters (`HAVING CASE @case WHEN '2x' THEN p2 != 0 WHEN '3x' THEN p3 != 0 END`) - where @case is a placeholder for $case (variable like parameter) transferring into.